# how to link_to between two different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I have two models a Vehicle and Student model. I am trying to link to my student show view from my vehicle index view. However when I use link_to I get the output to url of  `/students.0827312` and I need it as `/students/0827312` in my link to output and I'm not sure what I am missing. I am just trying to figure out what I need to call to get that **period** replaced with a **slash**.

vehicle.rb

```
class Vehicle < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = :vehicle_id
  belongs_to    :student, optional: true
```

student.rb

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
self.primary_key = :student_id
has_one :vehicle
```

/views/vehicles/index.html.erb

```
<%=link_to vehicle.student_id, students_path(vehicle.student_id) %>
```

`rake route` command

[image: Rake routes]

Comment: Just a note on terminology, you don't link between models. Models are back-end concepts that have no idea what a link is. You conceptually link between *actions*, which are the front-end handlers of requests.

Answer (score 0):

`students_path(vehicle.student_id)` needs to be `student_path(vehicle.student.id)`. The singular, since you're link to an instance of `student`, not plural.

You're passing an ID as the `:format` to `students_path`, which is for viewing the *index* of students, not a specific student.

Comment: When I pass in without the 's' it says that the route does not exist though?

Comment: It does exist, according to the routes you posted. `student` in the left most column is the helper name, it indicates `student_path` and `student_url` exist, and route `/student/:id` to `students#show`.